# problems while sending messages using ssl:send

Tags: erlang

I am writing some code which sends data over ssl sockets.
The sending part is inside a gen_server:call/3 as:

```
handle_call({send, Data}, _From, #state{socket=Socket} = State) ->
    Reply = case ssl:send(Socket, Data) of
       ok ->
          ok;
       {error, Error} ->
          {error, Error}
    end,
    {reply, Reply, State}.
```

the problem is that if i kill the application which behaves as server at the other side of the connection, the result of the call is 'ok' but the Data is not sent. Does that mean that the socket is viewed as alive untile {ssl_closed, S} is received by the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake, data is actually sent but never recovered by peer.